# Creating simple .htaccess URL rewrites

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having difficulty with simple re-writes in .htaccess on a hosted Apache server.

All the tutorials that I have read use regular expressions to make complex URLs more user-friendly, particularly dynamically-created URLs.

An example:
`RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]`
would change
`www.yoursite.com/product.php?id=123`
to
`www.yoursite.com/product/123`

However, that's not as user-friendly as I would like. In a site which uses dynamic URLs, I would like to change
`/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=97`
to
`http://www.example.com/product-name-a`

So, I tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   /index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=97   http://www.example.com/product-name-a
RewriteRule   /index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=98   http://www.example.com/product-name-b
RewriteRule   /index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=99   http://www.example.com/product-name-c
```

No errors are generated, but it doesn't work.

Is this possible to do? If so, is my syntax bad? If it's not possible, can anyone suggest ways of rewriting (not redirecting) individual URLs?

I'm aware that not using regular expressions means much more manual work. I am prepared for that. The data for this will come from a text file, which I will create. I'm not asking about DB access or anything relating to the origin of the data.

I do not believe that this is a duplicate question as:

- Other questions relate to rewriting or redirecting part content, not
  the complete URL.
- Other questions ultimately relate to regular expressions, as the
  requests are for manipulations, not replacements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Is this possible to do? If so, is my syntax bad?`

Problem that you are trying to match query string in `RewriteRule` which is incorrect since `RewriteRule` is used to match ONLY Request URI.

Change your rule to this to make it work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=97 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /product-name-a? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^product-name-a/?$ /index\.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=97 [L,QSA]
```

Here `RewriteCond` is using `THE_REQUEST` variable that represents original request received by Apache from your browser.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: The looks good, but I think that a virtual server is causing problems now.
Not Found.
The requested URL /<dir1>/<dir2>/public_html/example/product-name-a was not found on this server.

Comment: I now get "The requested URL /product-name-a was not found on this server".   That seems strange. It's a re-write, so why would it be looking for a URL that it should know does not actually exist?

Comment: Should I have made clear that I am looking to re-write the dynamic URL to a readable URL? The actual page product-name-a doesn't exist, it's a pseudonym for the dynamic URL.

Comment: That links to the products, but all re-writing disappears and the URL just appears as the original `/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=97`

Comment: 2nd rule rewrites internally without changing the URL. When I test this code I get `http://localhost/product-name-a` in my browser with `index.php` getting `main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=97` in query string.

Comment: My mistake, I missed that it was two RewriteRule  lines.

That works great. You have saved me a lot of time. If you would like to name a charity of your choice, I shall make a small donation in gratitude.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out. Redcross organization is my personal favorite since they are present everywhere. If you're satisfied with my answer you can mark the answer as accepted.